# Slim log writer with sqlite

Tags: sqlite, logging, slim

I have configured slim to write logs to log files as the standard way. But this is not effective when we want to search large and all the logs at a given time. So I want to write those logs to a separate sqlite DB.
My question is how can I set the log writer to write the messages (as done in the [Zend framework](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.log.writers.html#writing-to-databases)) ?

P S: I know that I can create a PDO object and use the queries. But I don't want to change the existing code. Just prefer to set the writer and let the framework do the job for me.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how exactly logging is implemented? Depending on that the community could suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this as follows,

Create the sqlite connection

```
$sqlite = new PDO('sqlite:./logs/log.db');
```

Create my own LogWritter similar to the framework

```
<?php

/**
 * Description of LogWritter
 *
 * @author Ruwantha.Lankathilaka
 */

class LogWritter {

    protected $sqliteConnection;

    public function __construct($connection) {
        $this->sqliteConnection = $connection;
    }

    /**
     * Write function will bypass the slim default LogWriter and will return 
     * last inserted log id which could be used as a reference
     * 
     * @param type $object will get the error message
     * @param type $level will get the error levels of \Slim\Log
     * @return mix if successfully logged will return the last insert id, else 
     * will return false
     */
    public function write($object,$level) {

        //Determine label
        $label = 'DEBUG';
        $message = (string) $object;
        switch ($level) {
            case \Slim\Log::FATAL:
                $label = 'FATAL';
                break;
            case \Slim\Log::ERROR:
                $label = 'ERROR';
                break;
            case \Slim\Log::WARN:
                $label = 'WARN';
                break;
            case \Slim\Log::INFO:
                $label = 'INFO';
                break;
        }

        $sqliteQuery = "INSERT INTO logs (lable,message) VALUES (:lable,:message)";
        $statement = $this->sqliteConnection->prepare($sqliteQuery);
        $result = $statement->execute(array(':lable'=>$label,':message'=>$message));

        if(!empty($result)){
            return $this->sqliteConnection->lastInsertId();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Add the LogWritter to the index

Add the LogWritter to the Slim app

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'log.writer' => $logWriter,
    'log.enabled' => true,
    'log.level' => \Slim\Log::DEBUG,
    'debug' => true
));
```

now you can get the log from app

```
$retult = $app->log->error('test error');
```

$result will have the inserted log id false if the log failed

Hope this will help someone in future.